# Method should wait until other method initiated by yet another method has finished

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, synchronization, task

I have method A (a Post request using System.Web.Mvc.Controller ) that calls <s>(and awaits)</s> the (long running) asynchronous method B (which creates PDF files).

If, in the mean time (while method A and B are still running) method C (another Post request) is called, method C should wait until method B has finished, because it needs the results (the PDF files) from that method.

I could call method B again from method C, but that would be redundant, since it is already running...

Which concepts exist to achieve this?

**Edit**

Some simplified sample code to show what I have now:

```
public class OrderController : Controller 
{

  private MyContext _context; //Set by Dependency Injection

  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> SaveOrder(Order order) {
      _context.Entry(order).Status = Modified;
      _context.SaveChanges();
      _ = GenerateAndSavePDF(order).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted); 
     // Ideally, if the SaveOrder method is called multiple times in a short period (when the PDF generation is already running from the previous save), the already running tasks should be stopped and only the latest one should be run (in order to get a PDF with the latest order information)
     return View(order); 
  }

  public async Task GenerateAndSavePDF(Order order) {
      var pdf = ...... // code to generate pdf
      order.pdf = pdf;
      _context.SaveChanges();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public async Task SendEmail(int orderId) {
     Order = context.Orders.FirstOrDefault(order => order.Id = orderId);
     var mail = ...... // code to generate mail;
     mail.attachment = order.pdf;  // <==== This is where I need to wait for method GenerateAndSavePdf to be finished before I can send the mail
     mail.Send();
  }
}
```

So if a user saves an order, the PDF gets generated. But if in the mean time, the users also chooses to send the email, the SendEmail method has to wait until the PDF is available...

Comment: What you are describing sounds like [async-await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: @Sweeper, I have edited my question, since I already use the async-await method (for method A calling method B); but I don't know how I can force method C to wait until method A (and therefore also method B) has finished....

Comment: Then I don't think you have fully understood the meaning of async/await. Can you show some code, demonstrating how you are using it now?

Comment: @sweeper, you might be absolutely right about my misunderstanding of asynchronous stuff. I will post some code later to show you what I am doing now.

Comment: @Sweeper I have added some simplified code to show what I have now

Answer (score 1):

Oversimplified example of what you need:

```
public class ExampleTaskTracker
{
    // the task we're awaiting if there one
    Task<object> task;

    // initiates the process
    public void Start()
    {
        if (task == null || task.IsCompleted)
            task = Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith((o) => new object());
    }

    // waits the process to finish if there's one
    public async Task<object> End()
    {
        if (task == null)
            return null;

        return await task;
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to use CancellationToken if you want to cancel the task at a certain point

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` is what you need.
Just make sure each of described metods returns either `Task` or `Task<T>` (and never `void`) and `var pdf = await GeneratePDF()` await it throughtout a whole callstack. That's it, as simple as that.

Keep in mind that you have few embarrassingly simple combinators in the `TPL`: `Task.WhenAny(...)` and `.WhenAll()` to introduce more complicated behaviours. For example, `.WhenAny(Task.Delay(timeout), ...)` is perfect for timeout-guarding long-running operations.

Another important options is `CancellationToken` which can be passed over to make your async operations cancellable. Say, timeout fired and you'd like to (at least, try to) stop background operation rather then let it burn your CPU uselessly; without `CancellationToken` it wouldn't be an easy goal, but luckily it becomes dead simple when `CancellationToken` presents.

Comment: Method A is already async, and awaits MethodB. But I need Method C to also await the end of MethodB

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll(MethodB(), MethodC())`.

Comment: You another post request thats call controller 's C method is independent from first post request. What i am suggesting can you set order/synch the 1st Post and 2nd Post request from UI/client ?

Answer (score 0):

Definitions:

- Method A: A post request using System.Web.Mvc.Controller
- Method B: Long running asynchronous which creates PDF files
- Method C: Controller method that wants the result

First of all, I would just have let Method A wait until B is ready and then return the result for it. That would work well and is the easiest solution.

If that's not what you want, I would see Method A as a job initiator which just returns a queue ticket which can be used to check the result.

To enable that, the class which contains method B must keep track of tickets and which `Task` they correspond to.

So you would have something like this in your controller:

```
public Task<string> MethodA(MyViewModel model)
{
    var businessEntity = Convert(model);
    return _pdfService.GenerateBuild(businessEnitty);
}

public Task<PdfContent> MethodC(string ticket)
{
    if (_pdfService.TryGet(ticket, out var pdf)
        return StreamContent(pdf.Stream);

    return HttpCode(425); //Too early
}
```

The return types/methods are incorrect, but I think that you can find the correct ones.

Then in the PDF service where method B is, you need to manage a queue. Also note that this class must be registered as a single instance in the IoC container, as it should survive between http requests (a new controller instance is created for every request).

Here is a very simple example:

```
public class PdfService
{
    Dictionary<string, Task> _workMap = new Dictionary<string, Task>();

    public string StartGeneration(PdfModel model)
    {
        var pdfBuilder = new PdfBuilder();
        var task = pdfBuildr.BuildAsync(model);
        var ticket = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        _workMap[ticket] = task;
        return ticket;
    }

    public bool TryGet(string ticket, out PdfDocument doc)
    {
        var task = _workMap[ticket);
        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            doc = task.Result;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Something like that. Do note that the code does not compile. It's here to illustrate a path that you can take.

Comment: I do not want methodA to have to wait for the result of methodB, since it can take some time, and that would block the user interface. I think I start to understand that I should separate some stuff and have some kind of queueing system. I am a self taught programmer and this kind of stuff is still quite a mistery for me...

Comment: My example is for queuing. I just create a list that matches the ticket that you return from Method A with the PDF creation task which is running in the backgound. Then Method C can poll to check if the PDF is ready.